# Hosting with network solutions data and cgi-bin folder missing

Tags: php, web-hosting

Strange problem .. I am getting the following error on my site

```
Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/data/9/1/106/108/1758271/user/1900303/cgi-bin/.php/sessions/sess_80f9a008cf3e9dee12465fb7dd902c48' (include_path='.:/usr/services/vux/lib/php') in Unknown on line 0
```

and I am unable to find the data or cgi-bin folder.. Will appreciate any help in this regard.

Comment: Have you tried contacting your hosting provider?

Comment: What code is triggering this error?

Comment: sounds like the host has an issue with the session save path.

Comment: Network Solutions .. they don't respond so quickly .. application is developed in PHP using Zend framework

Comment: My one sets `auto_prepend_file` and `auto_append_file`, so I removed those values in the root `.htaccess` file. You might have a similar problem.

Comment: What happens if you create a **completely blank** `test.php` file? Does the same error show?

Comment: its the same problem with info.php even ...

Comment: how can I override these values using .htaccess file auto_append_file and auto_prepend_file ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a session saving problem...

If you're waiting on the support for your hosting company to reply you could use the following PHP function to set the session save path for you.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php

Or, you can set it in a .htaccess file:

```
php_value session.save_path "<path here>"
```

Or, you can set it in PHP with the ini_set function.

As for the cgi-bin, can't you make those folders via FTP, or does your hosting provider not let you see above the document root?